# Terraform VPC In New Accounts

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-organizations

I want to work with multiple AWS Accounts/Organization-Units (Acct1/Acct2/etc) within an Organization. Creating a new Account (let's say Acct4) from the AWS Console results in the automatic creation of a VPC (let's say VPC4). Is there a way to create a new Account from Terraform (and control the creation of the resulting VPC)? Or if I wanted to track the VPC in the new Account, would I simply import the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account lets you create account in your org. Afaik you cannot control the vpc, but you can simply create a new vpc after the account was created and from then on forwards use only that vpc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you've answered my question.

Comment: @luk2302 post that as an answer

Comment: Yes, @luk2302 I will accept as the answer